# Why did Lenka's hair turn gold?

Tags: god-eater

Why did Lenka's hair turn gold when fighting Pita and afterward it returned normal ?

Comment: Because by then he was over 9000

Comment: Lenka turned Super.

Answer (score 1):

According to [/r/anime](http://reddit.com/r/anime):

> Golden hair status is supposed to be the effect that the Aragami Cells have on the human body when pushed to extremes.

So, basically, he was physically maxed out while fighting Pita, and as a result, his hair turned gold.